# Can I monitor multiple projects in one place using Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have multiple projects in GCP and I am trying to read all my projects' logs in one place.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike monitoring, Stackdriver logging UI does not provide a multi-project view of logs.

It is possible to query the logs from multiple projects using the API. See the resourceNames (or projectIds) field  https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/list

It's also possible to export logs from multiple projects to one place: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/

Answer (score 2):

You can check our documentation about [Monitoring multiple projects](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/accounts/guide#monitor-multiple-projects) using a single Stackdriver account that can contain up to 100 GCP projects for more details.

Answer (score 0):

A project organizes all your Google Cloud Platform resources. A project consists of a set of users; a set of APIs; and billing, authentication, and monitoring settings for those APIs. So, for example, all of your Cloud Storage buckets and objects, along with user permissions for accessing them, reside in a project. You can have one project, or you can create multiple projects and use them to organize your Google Cloud Platform resources, including your Cloud Storage data, into logical groups.

Users can only view and list projects they have access to via IAM roles. The Organization Admin can view and list all projects in the organization.

For logging you have to pass the project id:

`projects/[PROJECT_ID]/logs/`

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/